# Missing Push Notification Entitlement - development

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, app-store-connect

Good day,

I have developed more than 18 apps in Unity where I use local notifications. However, I have disabled `Push/Remote notifications`.

When I build an app for `TestFlight`, I receive a warning stating
`ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement`, even though I have turned it off in the client and in App Store Connect. This issue is occurring in 6 of my apps.

> Here is the full text of the warning: Dear Developer,
>
> We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
> "puzzle games" 2.18 (345). Your delivery was
> successful, but you may wish to correct the following issues in your
> next delivery:
>
> ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears
> to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app
> signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment'
> entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service,
> make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the
> Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a
> Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment'
> entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment
> entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is
> intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications
> in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the
> entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App
> Store Connect.
>
> Best regards,
>
> The App Store Team

While I am aware that this warning can be ignored, I need to fix it as it is not occurring in most of our apps. Here's what I have tried so far:

I turned off Push notifications from Notification in PlayerSettings.
I checked the capabilities in Xcode, where only "In-app purchase" was enabled.
I checked info.plist, all keys related to remote are set as false.
I checked Preprocessor.h for this line:

```
#define UNITY_USES_REMOTE_NOTIFICATIONS 0
```

Despite these actions, there has been no change. I am still receiving this warning.